# In Spring-Hibernate project how can I use getByKey(PK key) and saveOrUpdate(Obejct object) on the same table in a same row in a single transaction

Tags: spring, hibernate

Here in the following code when I invoke discoverAsync method by passing a node which is already in table, it should check that node id is exist in a table and update the other field in that row. But actually it is not happening, hiberbate is just selecting but not updating.

What my point of view is that we can not retrieve and update the same row at a same time in a same transaction. Please correct me if wrong.

Here is the code:

```
public Node discoverAsync(Node node) throws Exception {

    if(isNodeIdEqual(node))
        super.saveOrUpdate(node);
    else
        // TODO Raise Exception in case no node is available for discovery.

    return node;
}

public boolean isNodeIdEqual(Node node){
    String id = node.getId();
    String retrievedId = getByKey(id).getId();
    return id.equals(retrievedId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to check using your method `isNodeIdEqual`. Hibernate's `saveOrUpdate` will do that for you. If the record with a particular `key` is not found, it will save, if it found it will update by the `key`